# python+selenium xpath Unable to locate element

Tags: xpath

```
company_name = 'google'
browser.get('https://m.tianyancha.com/search?key=&checkFrom=searchBox')
ele = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='live-search']")
ele.clear()
ele.send_keys(company_name, Keys.ENTER)
name = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//div[@class='new-border-bottom pt5 pb5 ml15 mr15'][1]//a[@class='query_name in-block']/span/em")

if name.text:
    if name.text == company_name:
        check = '1'
    else:
        check = '0'
else:
    check = '0'
```

the error is :

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='new-border-bottom
>   pt5 pb5 ml15 mr15'][1]//a[@class='query_name in-block']/span/em"}

Comment: Without seeing the HTML there's no way of knowing why this failed. One possible problem might be that XPath searches for a literally exact match for the class attribute, but the class list was modified which could result in a class attribute value (which is just a string) with added, removed or re-ordered classes. You should probably use something like `div[contains(@class, 'new-border-bottom')]` if `.new-border-bottom` is the relevant class here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relative Xpath is wrong.

```
name = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//div[@class='new-border-bottom pt5 pb5 ml15 mr15'][1]//a[@class='query_name in-block']/span/em"
```

you cannot have `//` two times in your xpath. `//` means relative from the element you start with.

Check your Xpath for name.